# Resetting the origin of a transformed UIView descends into craziness

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-graphics

I rotate/scale a UIVIew using [UIView transform:] and this works well. However, as soon as I change the view's frame origin the contents of the view begins to scale 'weirdly' even though I am not performing any further CGAffineTransforms.

Why does this occur? How can I prevent it?

**Update 1:**

The docs suggest that the frame is invalid after a transform. Can I move the view via it's 'center' property instead?

**Update 2:**

Setting the views center did allow me to translate the view successfully after a transform had been applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I move the view via it's 'center' property instead?

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) defines the `center` property as:

> The center of the frame.

and says:

> The center is specified within the coordinate system of its superview.

I'd try it.

Answer (score 1):

From the UIView [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4):

> transform:
>
> **Warning:** If this property is not the identity transform, the value of
>   the frame property is undefined and
>   therefore should be ignored.

The center property is just a convenience method that really resets the frame's origin.

**Edit:** appended to answer comment:

If you're using the transform property and want to reposition your view, you have to concatenate the translation to your transform using:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, tx, tx);
```

Comment: I which case - how can I reposition the view?

Comment: I did try translating the view with an affine transformation but that created lots of complications which required me to manipulate the views anchor point.